# Output from SQL Server and C# different

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I believe something is wrong with my coding. It's not filtering by date I guess. Please help

SQL code:

```
SELECT
   CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) AS InvDate,
   i.InvoiceNo,
   i.EmployerCode,
   i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,
   '' AS Payment,
   pd.GivenName
FROM
   dbo.Invoice i
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.PatientDetails pd ON (pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID)
```

C# code:

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) AS InvDate, 
    i.InvoiceNo,
    i.EmployerCode,
    i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,
    '' AS Payment,
    pd.GivenName 
FROM
    dbo.Invoice i 
INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd ON (pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID) 
WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) 
    AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))," , objConn);
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Before i get kicked from here. I'll make some edits.

EDIT:

DateTime is in a 105 format (dd-mm-yyyy)

```
WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 )) 
AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105))
```

This is supposed to choose from a particular date. EG: from 11 Oct 2012 to 15 Oct 2012.

Even without DateTimepicker, The output doesn't show me "GivenName"

Comment: Your VB Code looks like C# code

Comment: Sorry about that changed the tags :)

Comment: How is your SQL code related to your VB code? If they're meant to be the same, your SQL code doesn't have the WHERE clause that is present in your VB code,

Comment: You should use a SQLparameter to send date in the where clause ... http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: I see what you mean, its supposed to filter by the date, thats the 2nd coding.

Comment: What is the format specified in your `DateTimePicker`, and what is the value of `dtpFrom.Text` ? You may put a breakpoint and debug it using visual studio, you probably got your formatting wrong. Also consider using parametrized queries. That will solve your problem. Passing values to the SQL query like this is never a good idea. Read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You're not really explaining what is *wrong* with the output you're realling getting.... care to elaborate? Just dropping two screenshots on us, letting us figure out from the two outputs, is not very helpful.... also: what **values** for `from` and `to` are you using in these examples?

Comment: Where is the "Where" clause in your DB Code ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775171/merging-data-from-2-tables/12776049#12776049

Comment: Please try to avoid treating dates as strings. Use [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)s to pass datetime values across to SQL Server (rather than passing as strings and attempting a `CONVERT` to get them back to `datetime`s), and I'm mystified as to why you'd format it as a fixed width, 80 character wide column in the `SELECT`.

Comment: How are you reading the result set? Are you using a DataReader, DataAdapter ?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry got busy.
marc_s, see edited question
MilindThakkar, see edited question
Habib, thank you for the advise
cbranch,thank you will have a look at it
@MrMoose, hi there, im using DataReader

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your loop where you go over the query results, and use the examine what dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("GivenName")) returns you. If you are still stuck, you can edit your question and add the code you are using to show how you are getting the data from the query results. You should be able to just follow a simple example such as the [one on MSDN for SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.90).aspx) to work out where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to format your input in dd/**MMM**/yyyy format. It better helps SqlServer to identify the month and day. I strongly recommend to use MMM format whenever you communicate with SqlServer.

```
DateTime fromDate, toDate;
fromDate = DateTime.Parse(dtpFrom.Text);
toDate = DateTime.Parse(dtpTo.Text);

SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) AS InvDate, 
i.InvoiceNo,
i.EmployerCode,
i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,
'' AS Payment,
pd.GivenName 
FROM    dbo.Invoice i 
INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd ON (pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID) 
WHERE datediff(d, '" + fromDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "', i.InvDate) >=0  
AND datediff(d, '" + toDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "', i.InvDate) <=0", objConn);
```

or if you have any constraint to do as above, convert the input using CONVERT()

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) AS InvDate, 
i.InvoiceNo,
i.EmployerCode,
i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,
'' AS Payment,
pd.GivenName 
FROM    dbo.Invoice i 
INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd ON (pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID) 
WHERE datediff(d, CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', 105 ), i.InvDate) >=0  
AND datediff(d, CONVERT(datetime, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', 105 ), i.InvDate) <=0", objConn);
```

Comment: Hi @vinodpthmn,

When i use MMM format it throws me a `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"` error.

When i use your 2nd option, the print out is as before, doesnt show me pd.GivenName in the txt file.

Comment: i'll try changing the globalization in the config file to see if that works.

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error is because you are passing invalid value in dtpFrom/dtpTo. You could try DateTime.TryParse() and second option is a lso not working because of the same reason. Please check the value in dtpFrom/dtpTo, make sure that you are passing proper datetime.

Comment: Hi @vinodpthmn,

I'm able to run the program without any errors this time. But the output doesnt show me pd.GivenName. Thats strange.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is due to conversion of type date to char, the filtering might not work as you expected . Try using datediff, it do the trick.

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) AS InvDate, 
i.InvoiceNo,
i.EmployerCode,
i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,
'' AS Payment,
pd.GivenName 
FROM    dbo.Invoice i 
INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd ON (pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID) 
WHERE datediff(d, '" + dtpFrom.Text + "', i.InvDate) >=0  
AND datediff(d, '" + dtpTo.Text + "', i.InvDate) <=0", objConn);
```

Comment: Hi, it was due to typo error (an additional comma near zero), removed that from above answer - please try again

Comment: Hi @vinodpthmn, thank you for helping me out. But it gives me another error. The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. If im not wrong, it doesnt specify the ISO of 105 which i require.