# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a query in SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) AS InvDate,
    i.InvoiceNo,
    i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,
    '' AS Payment,
    pd.GivenName
FROM
dbo.Invoice i
    INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd ON (pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID)
    WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '16/10/2012', 105)) AND 
(InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '16/10/2012', 105))
```

---

Output:

[image]

When i tried to put that into C#, it says "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

---

Info: 16/10/2012 are sample dates which i tried to insert into the query to make sure it runs. It's a old program, thats why its converting from a string. I'm pretty sure its something gotta do with the datetime format.  Had a look at http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/. But i cant put a finger through it.

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) 

AS InvDate,

i.InvoiceNo, i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment,pd.GivenName 

FROM

dbo.Invoice i INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd

ON 
(pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID)

WHERE

(InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 105)) 

AND 

(InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 105))", objConn);



        SqlDataReader objReader;
        objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\CMSExportedData\\Sales-" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs,   
System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

Comment: Did you tried yyyy/MM/dd or MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: If you really need to specify dates as string, you ought to use the language- and dateformat-independent format - ISO-8601. In SQL Server, this is either `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes!) or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` (if you need time, too). Those two are the **only** reliable way to specify a date as a string and it'll work for all your SQL Server locales.

Comment: Hi manish, tried both ways doesnt work.

Comment: Hi @marc_s, could you point me to a reference whereby i can change it? to eliminate specifying as strings?

Comment: @Newbie create a `Stored Procedure`. It allows you to pass parameters.

Comment: Yup reading up on that. I've never used Stored Procedure before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONVERT(datetime, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 105)` is attempting to convert the literal text `dd/MM/yyyy` into a `datetime` - that's never going to work.

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) 
AS InvDate,
i.InvoiceNo, i.TaxAmount + i.SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment,pd.GivenName 
FROM
dbo.Invoice i INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd
ON 
(pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID)
WHERE
(InvDate >= @StartDate) 
AND 
(InvDate <= @EndDate)", objConn);

objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate",/* some C# expression that gives you the start date, as a DateTime value */);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate",/* some C# expression that gives you the end date, as a DateTime value */);
```

You'll have to fill in the commented parts in the last two lines above. At a guess, from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832294/output-from-sql-server-and-c-sharp-different), they might be `dtpFrom.Value` and `dtpTo.Value`.

Comment: is this right?
`objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate",DateTime.Parse(dtpFrom.Text));`
`objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Parse(dtpTo.Text));`

Comment: @Newbie - no. *stop* converting the dates into strings. DateTimePickers (which I assume are what the `dtpX` controls are) have a `Value` property which gives you the date as a `DateTime` value. ADO.Net is perfectly capable of translating .NET `DateTime` values into SQL Server `datetime` values. Converting these into strings is an unnecessary conversion (and the source of many possible bugs). Just do `.AddWithValue("@StartDate",dtpFrom.Value)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your `SQL code`. You only need to `@` (*verbatim string literal*) before the double quote in your command if you have multiline string.

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT CONVERT(char(80), i.InvDate,3) AS InvDate,
               i.InvoiceNo, 
               i.TaxAmount +  i.SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment,pd.GivenName 
FROM    dbo.Invoice i INNER JOIN dbo.PatientDetails pd
            ON (pd.MedicalRecordID = i.MedicalRecordID)
WHERE   (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 105)) AND 
        (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 105))", objConn);
```

Comment: Oh, now it shows me something else. "Must declare the scalar variable "@SELECT"."

Comment: no, the `@` symbol should be outside the string `@"SELECT` not `"@SELECT`

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. My bad. Even with `@"SELECT`, it shows me the same error. Weird.

Comment: You don't think that trying to convert the string `'dd/MM/yyyy'` into a `datetime` is wrong?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it may be. but it I think `'dd/MM/yyyy'` in the query above is the date format which the OP is trying show instead of the original date.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to move the query to stored procedure and call the stored procedure from your Data Mapper Class.